# scratched ceramic pan

Tags: pan, ceramic

So I scratched my new ceramic pan by trying to cut something in it (definitely regretting that one) and was wondering if it can still be used? They are very small scratches. Can it even be restored?

Comment: What kind of ceramic pan? Most things will incur various scratches through normal use. For many items, that shouldn't affect the durability or usability.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe small, cosmetic scratches are a problem -- Those will happen over time and use anyway, and don't affect the cooking abilities of the pan. If you scratch through to the metal pan underneath (assuming it's cast iron), that would be a problem, and depending on the manufacturer you might be able to get it repaired/replaced.